# How do we sneeze? - Part 2

Tags: human-physiology

Here is the [second part](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/39438/how-do-we-sneeze-part-1?rq=1) of my question about how we sneeze. How are the sneeze droplets propelled at such a fast speed? I have heard sneeze travels at 100 mph. How is this possible?